# c# limiting listbox items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, listbox

I have this bit of code, which should be self explanatory:

```
    _item.Distance = Decimal.Round(dDistanceDec, 2);

    if (_item.Distance < 5)
    {
        tempItems.Add(_item);
    }
}

tempItems.OrderBy(i => i.Distance).ToList().ForEach(z => nearby.Items.Add(z));
```

(The bottom curly bracket closes a foreach loop if it makes a difference)

I am trying to limit the number of results to 10 in the 'nearby' listbox. I am a bit confused as it needs to sort them in order first of distance, but by doing that it is adding the items to the 'nearby' listbox. So where would the limiting code go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 tempItems.OrderBy(i => i.Distance)
           .Take(10)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(z => nearby.Items.Add(z));
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something to do with take!

Answer (score 3):

try to use `Take(10)` extension method that will return just 10 items.